# One subject for every paragraph?

Tags: pronouns, subjects, paragraphs

I've heard that a paragraph should have exactly one subject.  I'm looking at the caption of a figure, and wondering if it should be reworded:

> If the factor model is good, **it** interrupts the effect of M, but not S.  The residual at X, R, can only be due to single-cause confounders like S.  **It** acts as an instrumental variable when none of these single-cause confounders exist.

Here, the first **it** refers to the factor model; the second **it** refers to the residual.  Is there a rule that the subject should never change, or is it clear that a new subject has been introduced?

Because this is a figure caption, I don't feel like I can break it into two paragraphs.

Comment: One **topic** per paragraph.  (Can't make out what the paragraph is supposed to mean.)

Comment: You have misunderstood the word 'subject'.  What is meant in relation to what a paragraph is is not the grammatical subject of a verb, but 'subject' in relation to what a paragraph is.  A common definition is that the paragraph should constitute a single element/topic of a discussion.

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate for [writers.se]. It's not really about the English language, but about organizing writing.

Comment: @barmar Isn't this what Strunk and White, and Fowler wrote about?

Comment: @tuffy Right, that's what I wasn't sure about: whether subject meant topic or whether it meant that all pronouns had to refer to the same thing.

Comment: @NeilG Yes. And they've been translated into other languages, so their advice is not specific to English.

Comment: @barmar fair enough.

Comment: Voted to close: "belongs on the writing stackexchange. PS you maybe want to add an option for that stackexchange in the menu (only ELL and meta are options)."

Comment: Paragraphs are not linguistic structures, and therefore linguists have little useful to say about them.